# System.ArgumentException: type Parameter name: Type is not derived from a java type

Tags: android, xamarin, xamarin.android

hello I have a android app that is written in both xamrian native and xamrian forms i'm trying to get the app to open a page I did in xamrian forms when the user click's a button in this case button_1 however when I run this on a device and click said button I get a crash following by this error:

```
System.ArgumentException: type Parameter name: Type is not derived from a java type.
```

here's my code for the page that has the button on it:

```
using Android.App;
using Android.Content;
using Android.Views;
using Android.Widget;
using Android.OS;
using Xamarin.Forms.Platform.Android;

namespace ReadyMo.Droid
{
    [Activity(Label = "ReadyMO", MainLauncher = true, Icon = "@drawable/icon")]
    public class MainActivityHomeView : FormsApplicationActivity
    {

        Button button;


        protected override void OnCreate(Bundle bundle)
        {
            base.OnCreate(bundle);

            // Set our view from the "main" layout resource
            SetContentView(Resource.Layout.Main);




           //This is the button im having issues with!!!!!!

           //Code That opens the Settings Activity 

            button = FindViewById<Button>(ReadyMo.Droid.Resource.Id.button_1);

            button.Click += (sender, e) => {
                // this is our Xamarin.Forms screen
                StartActivity(typeof(SettingsView));
            };




        }




    //Code That Opens The Tips Activity!

    [Java.Interop.Export("Tips")] // The value found in android:onClick attribute.
        public void btnOneClick1(View v) // Does not need to match value in above attribute.
        {
            StartActivity(typeof(Tips));
        }

        //Code That Opens The Contact Activity!

        [Java.Interop.Export("contact")] // The value found in android:onClick attribute.
        public void btnOneClick2(View v) // Does not need to match value in above attribute.
        {
            StartActivity(typeof(Contact));
        }


        //Code That Opens The Modot Activity!

        [Java.Interop.Export("modot")] // The value found in android:onClick attribute.
        public void btnOneClick3(View v) // Does not need to match value in above attribute.
        {
            StartActivity(typeof(Modot));
        }


        //Code That Opens The Weather Activity!

        [Java.Interop.Export("wether")] // The value found in android:onClick attribute.
        public void btnOneClick4(View v) // Does not need to match value in above attribute.
        {
            StartActivity(typeof(Weather));
        }



        //Code That sends a email to mosema@sema.dps.mo.gov

        [Java.Interop.Export("email")] // The value found in android:onClick attribute.
        public void btnOneClick5(View v) // Does not need to match value in above attribute.
        {
            var email = new Intent(Android.Content.Intent.ActionSend);
            email.PutExtra(Android.Content.Intent.ExtraEmail, new string[] { "mosema@sema.dps.mo.gov" });
            email.PutExtra(Android.Content.Intent.ExtraSubject, "SEMA");
            email.PutExtra(Android.Content.Intent.ExtraText, "Sent Using The ReadyMO App");
            email.SetType("message/rfc822");
            StartActivity(email);
        }


        //Code That Opens Calls The State Emergency Management Agency !

        [Java.Interop.Export("call")] // The value found in android:onClick attribute.
        public void btnOneClick6(View v) // Does not need to match value in above attribute.
        {

            var uri = Android.Net.Uri.Parse("tel:5735269100");
                var intent = new Intent(Intent.ActionDial, uri);
                StartActivity(intent);
            }

        //Code That Opens The Fax Activity!

        [Java.Interop.Export("fax")] // The value found in android:onClick attribute.
        public void btnOneClick7(View v) // Does not need to match value in above attribute.
        {
            StartActivity(typeof(Fax));
        }




    }
    }
```

Any help would be amazing!

Thanks in advance! :)

Comment: Try to use TypeToken ) in native I use like "new TypeToken<MyModel>(){}.getType()"

Comment: Stepan Maksymov thanks for replying can you please be a little more specific? :)

Comment: @StepanMaksymov I am having the same issue on Xamarin.android when trying to start a service can you please elaborate your comment into an answer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

what ended up being the issue was the FormsApplicationActivity i changed:

```
[Activity(Label = "ReadyMO", MainLauncher = true, Icon = "@drawable/icon")]
    public class MainActivityHomeView : FormsApplicationActivity
    {
```

to:

```
[Activity(Label = "ReadyMO", MainLauncher = true, Icon = "@drawable/icon")]
    public class MainActivityHomeView : Activity
    {
```

and now it does not crash!